# Closure trailing variable

Tags: swift

I have this closure as variable:

```
public var cellClicked: (name: String, number: Int)?
```

How can I make it a trailing closure, so I can do something like:

```
        cell.cellClicked!{
            (str: String, n: Int) in
        }
```

Comment: You can also use `public var cellClicked: ((_ name: String,_ number: Int) -> Void)?` as tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have declared is `tuple` not the `closure`, If you want to make closure declared it like this.

```
public var cellClicked: ((String,Int) -> ())?
```

And make call like this

```
cell.cellClicked = { (name, value) in

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 3.0**
Try this.

```
public var cellClicked = (String, Int) -> Void

cell.cellClicked = {(str,n) in
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `public var cellClicked = (String, Int) -> Void` will compile without any error? Because it is not compiling on my `Xcode 8.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below :

```
func myMethod(completionHandler: @escaping (_ param : type, _ param2 : type) -> Void)
```

Description of **@escaping** -> https://cocoacasts.com/what-do-escaping-and-noescaping-mean-in-swift-3/